# VkSemaphoreSubmitInfo stageMask field for VkSubmitInfo2

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to fill out my VkSubmitInfo2 so that I can use VkQueueSubmit2, but I've got a stumbling block and a question:

Stumbling Block: What should stageMask be when filling out VkSemaphoreSubmitInfo?

Presumably, for the wait semaphore you grab the pWaitDstStageMask and stuff that into the stageMask.  In my case, this wait semaphore is binary and is coming from VkAcquireNextImageKHR so I want VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, no?

However, there is no such correspondence for the pSignalSemaphores.  In my case, the VkSemaphore is a binary semaphore going into the VkPresentInfoKHR structure which then goes to vkQueuePresentKHR.  What do I want for that stageMask?  VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_NONE?  VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT?  VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT?

Question: Why is deviceIndex the whole way down here?  That seems like a huge abstraction leak.  I presume there is a reason for it to be there, so could someone enlighten me on why?

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions here. spec: "`deviceIndex` is the index of the device within a device group that executes the semaphore wait or signal operation" Where else would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you choose the tightest stage you can get away with.

In case of wait, you choose the logically-latest stage possible. That means, if the GPU is capable of it, it will let proceed the work that require unrelated stages.

In case of signal, you choose the logically-earliest stage possible. That means, if the GPU is capable of it, the things that wait on that semaphore won't have to wait for unrelated work to finish as well.